# Authenticate Twitter from R

Tags: r, twitter

I am new to R and I'm trying to do a sentiment analysis with Twitter tweets. I've installed `twitteR` and `base64enc` and also updated `httr` package. But still after I input:

```
consumer_key <- 'XXX'
consumer_secret <- 'XXX'
access_token <- 'XXX'
access_secret <- 'XXX'
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key , consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

I got the error

```
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

I've no idea how to solve the problem, can somebody help?

Comment: Usually tokens expire after a while, make sure to use a valid one.

Comment: when you setup your app with twitter did you make your callback url:  `http://127.0.0.1:1410/` ? That generally is the reason i've found for this problem.